# How do I use numbers in a list as keys for my dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

My text file is a large list of data (by large meaning I can't format it by hand) consisting of only numbers and is formatted like this:

```
 1 5555 6666
 2 5555 6666
 1 7755 6666
 3 8888 6666
```

I would like to use the first two columns as my keys and the third remaining column as their value.

Here is my code:

```
import string
def load (filename):
    with open ('filename', 'r'):
        dict = {}
        for line in file.readline():
            key, site, value = dict([line.strip().split('\t')for line in file
            dict[key[0]]+[site[1]]= value[2]
        return dict
```

However my code fails.

My desired output is this:

`{('1', '5555'): '6666', ('2', '5555'): '6666', ('1', '7755'): '6666', ('3', '8888'): '6666'}`

Is it possible to achieve my output? Am I on the right track? If not, where did I go wrong and how can I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Keys have to be immutable, which lists aren't. Use tuples instead, which are immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the csv module to read the content splitting the elements by whatever delimiter you pass then  unpack and use the first two elements in a tuple as the key and the last as the value:

```
import csv

with open("in.csv") as f:
    d = {}
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ") # pass whatever your delimiter is
    for row in r: # first row  1 5555 6666 -> ["1", "5555", "6666"]
        a, b, v = row # a,b,c = "1", "5555", "6666"
        d[(a, b)] = v # create a tuple from the first two elements of the row
print(d)
{('3', '8888'): '6666', ('1', '5555'): '6666', ('1', '7755'): '6666', ('2', '5555'): '6666'}
```

If you want the data ordered use an OrderedDict:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
with open("in.csv") as f:
    d = OrderedDict()
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
    for row in r:
        a, b, v = row
        d[(a, b)] = v
print(d)
```

If you had a chance the the keys could repeat then you would  need to store the values in a list or some container:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
with open("in.csv") as f:
    d = OrderedDict()
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
    for row in r:
        a, b, v = row
        d.setdefault((a,b),[]).append(v)
print(d)
```

You own code has multiple mistakes:

```
def load(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f: # as f and pass variable filename not a string
        d = {} # don't shadow the python dict 
        for line in f: # iterate over the file object
            key, site, value = line.split() # unpack
            d[(key, site)] = value # already unpacked so just use the variables
        return d
```

Then call your function passing the filename:

```
print(load("in.csv"))
{('1', '5555'): '6666', ('3', '8888'): '6666', ('2', '5555'): '6666', ('1', '7755'): '66`66'}
```

Comment: I keep getting the error "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)." Does that mean it is not possible? Because like i said my text file is large.  @PadraicCunningham

Comment: @ShaunnaWilliams. There are a few possibilities. Which code did you try?

Comment: I tried the very first one you suggested @PadraicCunningham

Comment: @ShaunnaWilliams. How is your file delimited? Just the last code so we can rule out a few issues

Comment: Sir my file is tab delimited, are you sure that is the issue? I still cannot figure it out. @PadraicCunningham

Comment: @ShaunnaWilliams, `delimiter="\t"`, if the code still errors then you need to show me your input

Comment: I went and saved my text file as CSV comma delimited although it is tab. I am not sure how that affected my code but i  got the error: "ValueError: need one more value to unpack." Is there anyway I can show you my code? Perhaps email? I know PM is not available on stackoverflow  @PadraicCunningham

Comment: Okay never mind thank you so much Sir. I got it! But is there anyway to print my output vertically? I am fairly new to programming and if it is not possible that is fine. @PadraicCunningham

Comment: @ShaunnaWilliams, cool, when you say vertically what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You should not redefine built-in type `dict`. You should write correct python code:

```
def load(filename):
     with open('filename', 'r') as inp:
         result = {}
         for line in inp:
             key, site, value = line.strip().split('\t')
             result[key,site] = value
         return result
```